# не могу написать часть docker compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

Какая ситуация: у меня есть python код на DockerHub который требует при запуске ввод в консоль, когда его скачиваешь с докера нужно прописать флаг -it (что означает что контейнер будет запущен интерактивно). Я хочу написать для него docker compose но насколько я понимаю суть compose в том что он для единичных контейнеров заменяет длинную команду при скачивании с докера. Я нашел как сделать все кроме того что мой контейнер запускался интерактивно, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Comment: Зачем вам вообще compose для интерактивного контейнера?

Comment: А вообще непонятно как вы так искали, вот первая же ссылка из моего гугла https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249744

Comment: спасибо за ответ это помогло (я не умею гуглить(( )